# htaccess get https for a folder excluded from rewrites rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using Laravel, so I have rewrite rules to redirect to the index.php, I've rules to redirect to www and to https too.

I want URI "*/blog*" not to be redirected to index.php but I need it like:

https://www.example.com/blog

actually it redirects to:

```
example.com/blog
```

becouse this rule `RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)` exludes it form rewrite rules

This are my rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(blog) #I need this to get www and https but not further rules

# To https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# To www if is not a subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `blog/` to be skipped from `index.php` rewrite then change last rule to this:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^blog(/.*)?$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: I suppose so, but that URL is a Wordpress blog. Initially I did not redirect, I was still leaving example.com/blog (without https or www).
I configured the WP htaccess and now it works.
At first it gave me a 500 error if I did not put `RewriteCond $ 1! ^ (Blog)`, now I deleted that and your input and it works. I do not know why but I do not complain.